# Kendo Dropdown Filter Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to put the filter in my dropdown i am using `.Filter("contains")` but it seems it not working for me. I have gone through many docs its shows wt i have done is correct but still its not working.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("DropdownSourceDatasourceType")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%", @id = "DropdownSourceDatasourceType", @onchange = "changes=true;" })
            .OptionLabel("Select")
            .Filter("contains")
            .DataTextField("SourceDataSource")
            .DataValueField("SourceDataSourceID")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("Cascading_Get_Sources", "Admin")
                    .Data("filterClients");
                }).ServerFiltering(true);
            })
            .Enable(false)
            .AutoBind(false)
            .CascadeFrom("ClientName")
            .CascadeFromField("SourceDataSource")


            )
```

Comment: Below is the link i have referred"https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist"

Comment: You have specified a js method "filterClients" in the datasource read. Can you post that code too along with the parent drop down you're cascading from? Also how exactly is it not working - please add details to your question about how exactly it is currently performing vs what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see, your filter function anywhere in the code, you need to define a javascript function **filterClients** to make it work as,

```
function filterClients() {
        return {
            ClientId: $("#FirstDropDown").val()
        };
    }
```

please go through my article on this [Cascade DropDownList](https://www.sharpencode.com/article/KendoUI/cascade-dropdownlist)